# how to know radgrid master detail which of them in edit mode

Tags: telerik, radgrid, radcombobox

I'm using ASP.NET AJAX telerik control.

When I use radcombobox autocomplete in Radgrid control, it works.
But when I design it into master/detail radgrid, it failed.
Because the radcombobox autocomplete is in the master grid, when I into detail editmode, code behind ItemDataBound part trigger, cause an error.

So how can I do to trigger the ItemDataBound when Master in edit mode, but not trigger when detail in edit mode? or what condition that can tell which (master or detail) in edit mode?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can distinguish master and detail grid by using name property. Please try with the below code snippet.

**.ASPX**

```
<telerik:RadGrid> 
            <MasterTableView Name="Parent">
                <DetailTables>
                    <telerik:GridTableView Name="Detail"> 
                        <Columns>
                            .........
                            .........
                        </Columns>
                    </telerik:GridTableView>
                </DetailTables>
                <Columns>
                     .........
                     .........
                </Columns>
            </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

**.CS**

```
private void RadGrid1_ItemDataBound(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.GridItemEventArgs e)
{ 
    if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name == "Parent")
    {
        //Master table 
    } 
    else if (e.Item.OwnerTableView.Name == "Detail")
    {
        //Detail table
    } 
}
```